# Insert data when updating OroCRM Account

Tags: orocrm

I added a new field to the Oro account (* level * field) and some authorization rules for it.
When I'm updating an account, with a user with a role without access, the field level is not displayed, but the value of account level is cleared when I submet the form.

So I’d like to add the level every time I update an account. I tried to extend the account controller and change the update method with the following code:

```
protected function update(Account $entity = null)
{
    if (!$entity) {
        $entity = $this->getManager()->createEntity();
    }

    $authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

    if (!$authorizationChecker->isGranted('EDIT', new FieldVote($entity, 'level'))) {
        $entityFromDB = $this->getManager()->find($entity->getId());
        $levelFromDB = $entityFromDB->getLevel();
        $entity->setLevel($levelFromDB);
    }

    return $this->get('oro_form.model.update_handler')->update(
        $entity,
        $this->get('oro_account.form.account'),
        $this->get('translator')->trans('oro.account.controller.account.saved.message'),
        $this->get('oro_account.form.handler.account')
    );
}
```

However, when saving, the account level is changed to blank.

Can anyone give me some help? I'm using OroCRM 2.6.19

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have assigned the value too early and it is overridden when the form is submitted.

I recommend you to move the logic to [the doctrine even listener](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events) to `preUpdate` event, so it would be executed after the form is submitted and will override the data from the form.